# read() returns Bad file descriptor on a valid file descriptor

Tags: c, fcntl, unistd.h

In the following program,

```
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buf[8]={};

    remove("file.txt");
    fd = creat("file.txt",0666);
    write(fd,"asdf",5);
    perror("write");
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    perror("lseek");
    read(fd,buf,5);
    perror("read");
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is

```
write : Success
lseek : Success
Read : Success
asdf
```

But it shows

```
wriet : Success
lseek : Success
Read : Bad file descriptor
```

Can anybody tell me the reason? I can see that the string `"asdf"` if successfully written to `file.txt`

Comment: Please remember that you should only call `perror()` if something actually failed. If read() didn't fail, you could print an error that's related to code you ran prior to calling read().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manpage:

> The creat() function shall behave as if it is implemented as follows:
>
> ```
> int creat(const char *path, mode_t mode)
> {
>     return open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode);
> }
> ```

So, the file is opened in write-only mode and thus you cannot read.

If you need to read and write, use `open(...)` directly with `O_RDWR` instead of `O_WRONLY`.

### The `0666` you specified just indicates the permissions in the file system the file gets created with.

If you just want to do normal file I/O you could also use the high-level APIs such as [`fopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).

Comment: 0666 means that all users can read and write but cannot execute

Comment: You are mixing up file system permissions with file modes. `0666` means that any user can read/write the file, but it does not mean that the file handle in your code can do that.